# IBM Installation manger unable to Download/Install the remote repositories of WAS 9

Tags: websphere, application-server, ibm-installation-manager

IBM Installation manager comes up blank after hitting the Install button.
I am using Installation Manager 1.8.6 on x64 linux, and the "V9WASILAN" URL of the repository manager. I have no clues of the issue and attached is the screen shot of the errors from the installation manager logs. Also I tried both online and offline installation and none of them helped. I am suspecting that it is an issue from IBM repositories itself, does any one hitting the same issue ? Any help is much appreciated and please note that I do not have IBM Passport Advantage account and I don't think It is necessary for downloading and installing the developer edition.[Error From Installation Manager log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poDGy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need IBM Passport Advantage account to install from the V9WASILAN url. I do not have any problem with Installation Manager 1.8.6 and this url. It seems there is a network hiccup when your Installation Manager trying to download from IBM fix central. I can see there is DownloadPrematureEOFException in the log file. You can try again.

If you still have the problem, you can try to see whether you can download the file from your web browser directly.  The file url is logged in the Installation Manager log.

Comment: HI @Patricktiu as you suggested I have tried browsing the URL from the browser and I see that it is being blocked by our Barracuda site. I have got the following website http://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com white listed and now I see the following error printed Message ID : CRIMC1074E Explanation: Related files may be missing or files may be corrupted, or read access is not allowed.If this repository contains a repository.xml fileit may be out of date

Comment: You may need to open up more websites in order to talk to Fix Central.  See the IBM Fix Central Connectivity Considerations support document: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1014351